# React-native, how to build standalone android apk

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to build an apk file from a react-native for a couple hours now, but got nowhere, I do not need it to be signed, I just need it not to fetch files from js server, does anyone has a updated guide to achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below command from react-native project root directory.

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

This will generate debug apk in folder

> android/app/build/outputs/apk

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if you don't want it to be signed you just need to test it on a device? what you can do is follow this procedure https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html
also if you need the .apk its present in android/app/build/output/apk

or you could always do that

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

While both Ronak and Jickson answers are valid, you might run into trouble with gradle and the android compilation process, in my case my device wouldn't install the unsigned apk.

The easiest way to do this is simply follow the steps for a signed apk, they are not (overly) complicated and you should be able to install the apk without problems.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html